# How to print numbers from 1 to n using assembly language?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, qemu

I'm new to assembly language and I'm trying to print 1 to n numbers using assembly language, without using C libraries. I'm using qemu as my emulator for raspberry pi.

Here is a sample code that I tried

```
    .global _start
_start:
MOV R7, #3 @ Syscall read from keyboard
MOV R0, #0 @ Input stream keyboard
MOV R2, #1  @ Read 1 characters
LDR R1, =character @ Put number in R1
MOV R6,R1 @Holding value of R1 i.e. the input number 'n'
MOV R1,#0 @initialiing value 
MOV R2, #1 @counter
SWI 0

_loop:
AND R1, R1, R2 @Add one to each value of R1
B _write @print the value
SWI 0


_write:
MOV R7,#4 @ Syscall for output
MOV R0,#1 @ Output stream for R1
MOV R2,#1
CMP R1,R6 @Compare if the value is equal to 'n'
BNE _loop @if less than, then add again and print
SWI 0

end:
MOV R7,#1
SWI 0

.data
character:
.word 0
```

Please let me know, how is it supposed to be done.

Thanks

Comment: You need to explain what your program actually does, not just what it's supposed to do.  [mcve].  Does it assemble?  Does it crash?  Does it print something but not what you want?  Try running `strace ./a.out` to trace system calls, or run it under gdb.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: The above program does not work, It's supposed to take a input n, and serially print out all the values starting from 0 to n. For eg: if I enter 5, it should print 1 2 3 4 5. I search alot, but I cannot figure out what the issue is. Are there any examples that I could go through?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed several things that are not right. When a routine is called (`SWI`) registers can be changed so you should save the values in registers  that you are using (`push {r1, r2, r6, lr}`) and restore them after the routine (`pop {r1, r2, r6, lr}`), expectantly r1 and r2. The `AND` instruction is not a good adder, use `add`. In the `_loop:` there is an extra `SWI 0` instruction. In the `_write:` there needs to be the address of `character` in register `r1` and the data to write need to be in memory labeled `character` as a printable character (0x00000001 is not a printable character, adding 0x30 or decimal 48 would make it a printable character).

My modification to your program are in lower case. I added the `main` to the top in case you wish to use `gdb`. I skipped / bypassed the input and hard coded the input.

```
    .global _start
main:
_start:
@MOV R7, #3 @ Syscall read from keyboard
@MOV R0, #0 @ Input stream keyboard
@MOV R2, #1  @ Read 1 characters
@LDR R1, =character @ Put number in R1
@MOV R6,R1 @Holding value of R1 i.e. the input number 'n'
@MOV R1,#0 @initialiing value
@MOV R2, #1 @counter
@SWI 0
mov  r6, #5
mov  r1, #0
mov  r2, #1

_loop:
@AND R1, R1, R2 @Add one to each value of R1
add  r1, r1, r2
B _write @print the value
@SWI 0


_write:
push {r1, r2, r6, lr}
add  r3, r1, #48
ldr  r0, =character
str  r3, [r0]
MOV R7,#4 @ Syscall for output
MOV R0,#1 @ Output stream for R1
ldr r1, =character
MOV R2,#1
SWI 0
pop {r1, r2, r6, lr}
CMP R1,R6 @Compare if the value is equal to 'n'
BNE _loop @if less than, then add again and print

end:
MOV R7,#1
SWI 0

.data
character:
.word 0
```

Assemble, link and output

```
as -o count2.o count2.s
ld -o count2 count2.o
./count2
12345
```

ADDITION:

I have not used QEMU but looking at https://azeria-labs.com/load-and-store-multiple-part-5/ I think the problem may be access to memory storage. Try this and see if it makes a difference. I also changed the `push` and `pop` instruction.

```
    .global _start
_start:
@MOV R7, #3 @ Syscall read from keyboard
@MOV R0, #0 @ Input stream keyboard
@MOV R2, #1  @ Read 1 characters
@LDR R1, =character @ Put number in R1
@MOV R6,R1 @Holding value of R1 i.e. the input number 'n'
@MOV R1,#0 @initialiing value
@MOV R2, #1 @counter
@SWI 0
mov  r6, #5
mov  r1, #0
mov  r2, #1

_loop:
@AND R1, R1, R2 @Add one to each value of R1
add  r1, r1, r2
B _write @print the value
@SWI 0


_write:
@push {r1, r2, r6, lr}
stmdb sp!, {r1, r2, r6, lr}
add  r3, r1, #48
@ldr  r0, =character
ldr  r0, character_address
str  r3, [r0]
MOV R7,#4 @ Syscall for output
MOV R0,#1 @ Output stream for R1
@ldr r1, =character
ldr r1, character_address
MOV R2,#1
SWI 0
@pop {r1, r2, r6, lr}
ldmia sp!, {r1, r2, r6, lr}
CMP R1,R6 @Compare if the value is equal to 'n'
BNE _loop @if less than, then add again and print

end:
MOV R7,#1
SWI 0

character_address:
.word character

.data
character:
.word 0
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for which registers Linux system calls clobber in the ARM EABI?  On most platforms, Linux system calls clobber as few registers as possible (usually only the return value, but x86-64 also clobbers `rcx` and `r11` because `syscall` makes that unavoidable.)  I'd be surprised if ARM Linux EABI clobbered all its input registers, but of course it's possible.

Comment: If you're pushing registers to the stack anyway, you might as well just pass the stack address of your character instead of using a static location for it.

Comment: @Peter Cordes  Page 14 of http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf gives guidelines for ARM registers usages. Registers r0 - r3 are at risk mostly.

Comment: That's the *function*-call convention.  It doesn't mention SWI, and points out that it's NOT a full ABI (search for "linux" inside that document).  You should expect them to be different, because for example i386 Linux (System V psABI) clobbers `eax`,`ecx`, and `edx` on function calls, but only `eax` (with the return value) on system calls.

Comment: hi! I got segmentation fault while running the above code. Did you run this?

Comment: Yes I ran it on a Raspberry Pi and received the results posted.

Comment: I'm still getting segmentation fault. Is there any chance you could verify and run this on qemu?

Comment: Also, are there any web based tutorials that I could follow inorder to learn ARM?

Comment: A search of `arm assembly` on the web will return lot of websites. To isolate your segmentation fault, start with something simple like `.global _start`, `_start:`, `MOV R7, #1`, `SWI 0`. If that runs , continue to build more sections before the end. If that fails, the problem may be in how QEMU is started of configured. I do not have access to QEMU.